# Registered User password from DB and entered password during login do not match

Tags: php, hash, sha256

I have registered a new user and saved the username, password & salt in the DB using the following hashing method:

```
    if(isset($_POST['register']))
    {
    $password = $_POST['password']

    function sanitize($data)
    {
        $data=trim($data);
        $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data=mysql_real_escape_string($data);
        return $data;
    }

    $password = sanitize($password);

    function createSalt()
    {
        $salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32,MYCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
        $hash = hash("sha256", $salt);
        $final = $salt.$hash;
        return $final;
    }

    $hashedPassword = hash("sha256", $password);
    $salt = createSalt();
    $hashedPassword = hash("sha256", $hashedPassword.$salt);

    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO users(username, password, salt) VALUES('%s','%s','%s')",$username, $hashedPassword, $salt);
}
```

And Later while trying the login.php, I am entering the same password which I saved during registration and using the below code to check if the entered password is the same as the one in the DB

```
if(isset($_POST['login']]))
{
            $password = $_POST['password']

    function sanitize($data)
    {
        $data=trim($data);
        $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
        $data=mysql_real_escape_string($data);
        return $data;
    }

    function validateUser()
    {
        session_regenerate_id (); //this is a security measure
        $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }

    $password = sanitize($password);

    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '%s'",$username);
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($sql);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    if($count<1)
    {
        echo $count;
        unset($_POST['login']);
        header("location:login.php");
        exit;
    }

    $hash = hash("sha256", $password);
    $salt = $row['salt'];
    $hash = hash("sha256",$hash.$salt);

    echo $hash."<br />".$row['password']."<br /><br />";

    if($hash != $row['password'])
    {
        unset($_POST['login']);
        header("location:login.php");
        exit;   
    }
    else
    {
        validateUser();
        unset($_POST['login']);
        header("location:index.php");
        exit;   
    }
}
```

These passwords are not getting matched.
Kindly let me know what's wrong in this code.

Comment: It's hard to tell with the little code you've shown.  Is `$hash = hash("sha256", $password);` the same as `$hash = hash("sha256", $row['password']);`?

Comment: @cegfault: Updating the code above.. please advice!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

the salt value stored in the database is truncated because the varchar value is low increase the varchar value of your salt column to 200-300 something and than try this.. it will run fine.

I facepalmed when I found out this was screwing the result..

Dins

Comment: Yes. that fixed the issue... the varchar value was only 64.. updated it to 200.. it is workin now.. Thanks Dinesh!!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually i didn't see why this should not work, the code you have shown, should produce the same value, maybe you could check, whether the salt you read from the database is really the same as you wrote to the database.

Nevertheless i would not engourage to go further on this route, there are quite a lot of problems here.

1. First of all, SHA-256 is not a good choice to hash passwords, instead use a slow key-derivation function like **BCrypt**.
2. You should not escape input data without need, and if you need to escape them, you should do it only for the specific target system (`htmlspecialchars` and `mysql_real_escape_string` make no sense if you are going to calculate a hash anyway).
3. To create a salt, you use the random source, that is good. Using a hash afterwards creating the salt, will in no way make the salt more random.
4. There is no need to have two separate fields for password and salt in the database. Php's `crypt()` function will create a hash value, that already contains the salt.

I would invite you to read this tutorial about [hashing passwords](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/hash.html), you will find a PHP example too, and i would recommend to use the [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) library.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the information. I am new to php development. I will make a note of this while coding and make changes in my present.
However, my reported issue is fixed.. It was because of varchar value fixed for Salt column. Updated it to 200 from 64 charaters

Comment: @Roshan Raikar - That's what i thougth too (checking the database value), but it's good to hear that you could solve your problem. Anyway have a look at the tutorial, you will save time later and it makes the database even simpler.